# Отправка формы с POST запросом

Tags: php, форма

Привет, народ.
При отправке формы с POST запросом, при обновлении страницы спрашивает о повторной отправке формы. Если подтвердить, отправляется снова. Как можно этого избежать?

Вот код отправки.

```
   <?if(isset($_POST["NAME1"]))
    {
  $result = mail("program@eaxs.ru","Запрос на бронирование", "Вас просит    перезвонить $_POST[NAME1] по телефону $_POST[PHONE1] из города $_POST[CITY1]");
      if($result == 1)
{
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>Отправлено</span>";

}
else
{
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>Ошибка</span>";

}
 }
  ?>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

после получения и обработки POST данных делать редирект на предыдущую страницу. Поищите по сайту. Этот вопрос уже поднимался не раз.